# "unresolving" a deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

In short, is there a way to "unresolve" a deferred object?

For example: We have a list of data that needs to be updated periodically, or when an event is triggered. It would be great to take a deferred object created with .ajax() and pass it's promise around to gather callbacks. Then "fire" that ajax request whenever we want and have all the callbacks react. Is that possible?

Cheers

Comment: This is simply my opinion, I would say deferreds is not the solution you are looking to use for this particular problem. I am quite unclear on what you mean exactly by "passing the promise around to gather callbacks", if you could maybe be more specific... some pseudo code or something?

Comment: yeah, was going for some simple data binding using deferred objects. But, you're right, they aren't exactly suited.

Comment: Some kinda hack around http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/ would probably have gotten you there.

Comment: Yeah, digging around in the code I found that deferreds throw away their callback functions after their run. And if you mess with it so it holds onto them, then they're all called whenever you add a new callback with .done(), or .then(), etc. So you have to overwrite that behavior. Easier just to write something completely different.

Comment: perhaps you can add your resolution as an answer so that this question can be transitioned to the answered state.

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 1.7, there is [`progress()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) that can be used for multi-fire situations.